# how to get parent element id in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react with typescript. I am getting some data from the back-end API then I am rendering the data using the `map` function. The map function is to return a card in which I have two buttons and I want to perform some action based on the  `key` that I provided on the map function.

As one of two buttons, there is a delete button which is sending the `id` of the card to the server for deletion.

```
              {items &&
              items.map((data) => {
                if (option[index]) {
                  return <Grid item lg={3} md={4} sm={6} xs={11} key={data.Id}>
                    <Card className="home-card">
                      <CardMedia
                        component="img"
                        height="256px"
                        image={homeimg}
                        alt="green iguana"
                      />
                      <CardContent>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                          {data.name}
                        </Typography>
                      </CardContent>
                      <CardActions>
                        <Button size="small" variant="contained">
                          More Details
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                          size="small"
                          variant="contained"
// Here I want to get the key that I provided to the Grid element
                          onClick={handleClickOpen}
                        >
                          Delete
                        </Button>
                      </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                  </Grid>
                }
              })}
```

what is the best way to get that key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the map function effectively returns all data for that iteration of the current `items` you can simply access the value you pass to the key any time in that function. Assuming you want to handle the key value in `handleClickOpen` you can pass the value as a method parameter.

You will also likely want to pass to the onClick a function otherwise you will run into the `handleClickOpen` as soon as the component is rendered rather than when the user clicks the button.

Lastly, just a stylistic choice but you can also [destructure the values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of the data in your items

```
             {items &&
              items.map({Id, name} => {
                if (option[index]) {
                  return <Grid item lg={3} md={4} sm={6} xs={11} key={Id}>
                    <Card className="home-card">
                      <CardMedia
                        component="img"
                        height="256px"
                        image={homeimg}
                        alt="green iguana"
                      />
                      <CardContent>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                          {name}
                        </Typography>
                      </CardContent>
                      <CardActions>
                        <Button size="small" variant="contained">
                          More Details
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                          size="small"
                          variant="contained"
                          onClick={() => (handleClickOpen(Id))}
                        >
                          Delete
                        </Button>
                      </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                  </Grid>
                }
              })}
```